# Typescript: Compile files without mirroring the directory hierarchy

Tags: javascript, compilation, gruntjs, typescript, gulp

I am using VS Code for making an HTML5 game with TypeScript (JS). The project is getting a little bigger and I want to store the output in a different directory. 
The problem is that whenever I compile everything, it mirrors the original  directory hierarchy. So for example:

```
-dir1
--dir2
--dir3
---dir4
```

outputs:

```
-dir1
--dir2
--dir3
---dir4
```

(the same)

and I want:

```
-dir1
*.js
```

I've tried Grunt/Gulp/VSCode's own TaskRunner but nothing works and "keepDirectoryHierarchy" seems depricated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. I made a custom `Grunt` task which is not optimal but does the job.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-typescript");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-watch");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');

    grunt.initConfig({
        typescript: {
            base: {
                src: ['./client/**/*.ts'],
                dest: './temp',
                options: {
                    'module': 'commonjs',
                    target: 'es5',
                    sourceMap: true
                }
            }
        },
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [
                    {
                        src: ['./temp/**/*.js', './temp/**/*.js.map'],
                        dest: './build/',
                        flatten: true,
                        expand: true
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        clean: [
            './temp'
        ],
        watch: {
            scripts: {
                files: ['./client/**/*.ts'],
                tasks: ['typescript', 'copy', 'clean']
            }
        }
  });

  grunt.registerTask("default", ['typescript', 'copy', 'clean', 'watch']);
};
```

Comment: I've moved your solution from the question to your answer. Please do not post solutions in questions.

Answer (score 2):

## **VS Code support two way of typescript compilation:**

1. Native compilation using ***tsconfig***
2. Using JavaScript *Task Runner* such as **Gulp** or **Grunt**

### Native compilation using ***tsconfig***

1. Create file tsconfig.json in root dir
   [image]
2. Put next configuration in it

   ```
    {
      "version": "1.6.0-beta",
      "compilerOptions": {
         "target": "es5",
         "declaration": true,
         "noImplicitAny": false,
         "removeComments": true,
         "noLib": false,
         "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
         "sourceMap": true,
         "listFiles": true,
         "outDir": "",
         "out": "./Compiled/mycompiled.js", // here specify your output file( it would be contain all your compiled ts file in one) 
         "experimentalDecorators": true
      },
      "files": [ // file list (optional)
        "somefile.ts"
      ]
   }
   ```
3. Configure VS Code task runner
   [image]

### Using JavaScript *Task Runner* such as **Gulp** or **Grunt**

Current example show how you should modify your **gulpfile.js** to compile your project using [gulp-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript)

```
gulp.task('build', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src('src/**/*.ts') // here specify your file location or folders
                     .pipe(ts({ // gulp-typescript configuration
                               noImplicitAny: true,
                               out: 'output.js'// here specify your output file( it would be contain all your compiled ts file in one) 
                              }));

    return 
        tsResult.js
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./')); // here you can specify your output directory too
});
```

### Problem Solution

For your case you can choose both solutions. Pay attention for code comments and specify out directories and name of compiled js file as you wish.

Good Luck!

### Resources

1. [Gulp Typescript NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-typescript).
2. [Using TypeScript in Visual Studio Code (MSDN Blog)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/04/30/using-typescript-in-visual-studio-code.aspx).
3. [Typescript tsconfig.json specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json)
4. [Using Task Runner in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to give Gulp or another task runner a look. You will need a few steps to achieve what you are looking for.

- Compile Typescript
- Concatenate the files
- Cleanup the extra files

I use a similar system with CoffeeScript and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Gulp should work. You can use [the `flatten` plugin](https://github.com/armed/gulp-flatten):

I would use gulp-flatten:

```
var flatten = require('gulp-flatten');
gulp.task('compile', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.ts')
   .pipe(tsc())                    //compile them
   .pipe(flatten())                //change their relative path to point to one dir
   .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));      //write them in destination
});
```

Comment: I tried `gulp-flatten` to flatten the output of a TypeScript compilation but I ended up with a messed up sourcemap. The problem was not *immediately* evident because the sourcemap was created but when I tried actually using it, it did not work. When I looked closer, one of the symptoms of the problem was that the sourcemap produced by tsc contained a `sourcesContent` field, but after flattening, it was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am using rollup with the typescript plug-in to do this type of work.

```
npm i rollup
npm i @rollup/plugin-typescript
```

Then follow the documnets in these respective libraries.